# How to get dynamically created kendo combobox value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I have one form for user informations and i'm creating some elements dynamically with kendo controllers (combobox,datepicket, etc.)

I can create them successfuly but when i can get the value of selected item combobox or value of selected date from datepicker , it returns to me empty string.

Here is my view page:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Name("cmb"+number)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 150px;" })
        .DataTextField("myText")
        .DataValueField("myId")
        .DataSource(binding => binding.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("SetOptions", "List", new { id = number});
        }))
    )
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
      .Name("lyldt"+number).Format("yyyy-MM-dd")
    )
```

With this format i can create the controls but i cant get value of controls

Here is SetOptions function return

```
List<ComboClasses> list = new List<ComboClasses>();
        ComboClasses c = new ComboClasses();
        list.Add(new ComboClasses()
        {
             myText = "Married",
             myId = 1
        });
        list.Add(new ComboClasses()
        {
             myText = "Single",
             myId = 2
        });
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Here my javascript code:

```
         function CreateLoyaltyCard() {
var card = $("#cmbLoyaltyCards").data("kendoComboBox").value();
var cardt = $("#cmbLoyaltyCardsTypes").data("kendoComboBox").value();
var name = $("#lyltxtname").val();
var surname = $("#lyltxtsname").val();

var table = document.getElementById('tblLoyalty');

var rowLength = table.rows.length;
var dict = {
    loyalty: []
};
for (var i = 4; i < rowLength; i += 1) {

    if (i != rowLength - 1) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var mandatory = false;
        var cellLength = row.cells.length;
        for (var y = 0; y < cellLength; y += 1) {

            if (y == 0) {
                var cell = row.cells[0];
                var celtext = cell.textContent.toString();
                var div = celtext.indexOf("*");
                if (div >= 0) {
                    mandatory = true;
                }
            }
            if (y == 2) {

                var cell = row.cells[2];
                var tip = cell.children[1].textContent;
                var number = cell.children[2].textContent;
                if (tip == "text") {
                    var myval;
                    if (mandatory) {
                        myval = cell.children[0].value;

                        dict.loyalty.push({
                            "number": number,
                            "tip": tip,
                            "mvalue": myval
                        });
                        if (myval == null || myval == "") {
                            $('#lblMessageLoyalty').text("Please Fill all mandatory fields");
                            $('#LoyaltyOKWindow').data('kendoWindow').center().open().refresh();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        myval = cell.children[0].value;
                        var myArr = [number, tip, myval];

                        dict.loyalty.push({
                            "number": number,
                            "tip": tip,
                            "mvalue": myval
                        });
                    }
                }
                else if (tip == "select") {
                    var myselectval;
                    if (mandatory) {
                        myselectval = $("#cmb" + number).data("kendoComboBox").dataItem();

                        dict.loyalty.push({
                            "number": number,
                            "tip": tip,
                            "mvalue": myselectval
                        });
                        if (myselectval == null || myselectval == "") {
                            $('#lblMessageLoyalty').text("Please Fill all mandatory fields");
                            $('#LoyaltyOKWindow').data('kendoWindow').center().open().refresh();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        myselectval = $("#cmb" + number).data("kendoComboBox").value();
                        dict.loyalty.push({
                            "number": number,
                            "tip": tip,
                            "mvalue": myselectval
                        });
                    }
                }
                else if (tip == "date") {
                    if (mandatory) {
                        var datepicker = $('#lyldt' + number).data('kendoDatePicker');
                        datepicker = kendo.toString(datepicker.value(), 'yyyyMMdd');
                        dict.loyalty.push({
                            "number": number,
                            "tip": tip,
                            "mvalue": datepicker
                        });
                        if (datepicker == null || datepicker == "") {
                            $('#lblMessageLoyalty').text("Please Fill all mandatory fields");
                            $('#LoyaltyOKWindow').data('kendoWindow').center().open().refresh();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var datepicker = $('#lyldt' + number).data('kendoDatePicker');
                        datepicker = kendo.toString(datepicker.value(), 'yyyyMMdd');
                        dict.loyalty.push({
                            "number": number,
                            "tip": tip,
                            "mvalue": datepicker
                        });
                    }
                }
                else if (tip == "numeric") {
                    var mynumval;
                    if (mandatory) {
                        mynumval = cell.children[0].value;
                        dict.loyalty.push({
                            "number": number,
                            "tip": tip,
                            "mvalue": mynumval
                        });
                        if (mynumval == null || mynumval == "") {
                            $('#lblMessageLoyalty').text("Please Fill all mandatory fields");
                            $('#LoyaltyOKWindow').data('kendoWindow').center().open().refresh();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        mynumval = cell.children[0].value;
                        dict.loyalty.push({
                            "number": number,
                            "tip": tip,
                            "mvalue": mynumval
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea ? Why doing this or what i missing?

Thanks

Comment: what does `SetOptions` returns? maybe it missig `myId` property?

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas i also checked that it returns Json List but its not empty

Comment: I edited also the question add some detail @MantasČekanauskas

Comment: Have you checked `$("#cmb" + number).val()`?

Comment: Yes... Its also returns  "" @mrmashal

Comment: Get the select item: `$("#cmb" + number).data("kendoComboBox").dataItem();` the "value" will then be whichever property you want, which looks like it might be `.myId`

Comment: With your given code everything works just fine. It only returns empty string if nothing is selected.

Comment: Note that your widget will fill it's information by an async request, so if you're running `value()` function before that request is complete, it won't be ready actually.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown can you explain more like how value is not ready?

Comment: I first fill the component than select by user and than when i submit form it returns empty string @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: Try adding more code. Its hard to guess without information

Comment: I added all Javascript code @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: When I change the name of combobox it works. Its very interesting...